# Finding the first space after a set of numbers in a string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a string which includes some serial numbers, and I want the index of the first space after the first set of numbers.

```
exampleString = '  2342342 hihihello goats'
findDesiredSpace(exampleString)
```

desired output of the index of the space after 2342342 = 9

I've tried some variations of exampleString.find(' '), but I'm uncertain of the number of preceding spaces.

Is there a simple way of getting the index I'm looking for? Should I increment through the spaces found through exampleString.find(' ') and check if there's a nonwhitespace character in front of it to find my desired index?

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes, there is. Have you tried anything? Also, note that (as far as Python is concerned, at least) the index of the space is `9`.

Comment: What should the output be if the string is `"1a 2 3"`? 3 or 5?

Comment: @Rawing, the output should be 3. The first set of nonwhitespace characters will always be integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can approach that with regular expressions getting the [`end()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end) of a match:

```
>>> import re
>>> exampleString = '  2342342 hihihello'
>>> re.search(r'\d+\s', exampleString).end()
10
```

where `\d+` would match one or more consecutive digits, `\s` would match a space character.